# Wordpress development theme link bootstrap.css to index.php not working?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am developing my Wordpress theme from scratch and when I link my bootrap.css in my index.php file and then I go see what it looks like it did not work.  Please if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to the site that you're working on? I'd love to help but really need to see what you're doing. Here are a couple things you can try:

- link bootstrap.css in the header.php template file. As long as the directory path is correct, you should be able to 'view source' on the page and click on the file link to confirm that the file's content has been loaded.
- Don't forget that for bootstrap, you also need to load jquery (http://jquery.com/download/) as well as link to the bootstrap.js file. I usually link to jquery and the bootstrap.js file in the footer.php template file for your theme.
- You can also always refer back to this basic template which bootstrap provides that should help you get started. 
  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template